# Memory efficient value replacement in a matrix/raster

Tags: r, memory, matrix, replace, raster

I am editing a set of raster (or matrices if you'd like) that are set in a rasterstack (a list). I need to change the value -999 to NA. So far I've found the following code, which I run on each separate raster, to be the most memory efficient

```
r[[15]][r[[15]]==-999]<-NA
```

or

```
s=r[[15]]
s[s==-999]<-NA
gc(reset=T)
r[[15]]=s
```

I'm replacing the values over 20ish rasters in the list and around 10-15 I run out of memory. Does anyone know of a more efficient way?

Cheers!

Comment: Does the solution below work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `calc` which is designed to do this...

```
calc( r , function(x) { x[ x == -999 ] <- NA; return(x) } )
```

It'll return a `rasterStack` (or whatever was the input). From the docs:

> **`calc`** For large objects `calc` will compute values chunk by chunk. This means that for the result of `fun` to be correct it should not depend on having access to *all* values at once.

Comment: what's the extra `[]` for?  is this something specific to the `stack` package, or something else; can turn this into a real question you you want…

Comment: @SamMason it's the `raster` package. It's just an accessor to get at the actual values in the `rasterLayer` which returns a vector of those values. But I'm actually changing my mind after some additional testing and thinking it is not really needed now so thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I see it appears in the package docs a bit.  Not seen that syntax required elsewhere, maybe a hangover from programming other languages?

Comment: Nope, I did see it in r-sig-geo somewhere and it helped me in some situation, but I can't remember what and it seems to work just fine without it.

Comment: @SamMason nice blog site btw!

Comment: which blog site? lost the reference

Comment: :) hum, not sure if it's a blog, not been updated for a long time either!

Comment: Thanks for the response @SimonO101! The code worked! I'm trying to implement it into clusterR: 

'for (i in 1:length(nlist)){
  r=raster(nlist[i])
  clusterR(r, calc(x , function(x)  x[ x == -999 ] <- NA; return(x) 
        , filename=paste(names(r)), format="GTiff")
    
})`

Which only gives "Unexpected }" ?

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad I personally have never found that to speed up my code. I am not sure why because it *should*. Perhaps you can ask that on r-sig-geo mailing list. The package author is on there a lot.

Comment: @SimonO101, I implemented the function in a loop, which seemingly works fine, BUT the remaining values are being edited somehow. E.g the max value goes from 168.9 to 173.2 in one raster.

`for (i in 1:length(nlist)){
  r=raster(nlist[i])
  calc( r , function(x) { x[ x == -999 ] <- NA; return(x) } ,overwrite=T, filename=paste(names(r),"NA_edited"), format="GTiff")
} `

Have I missed out on something here? Care to follow up on that one?

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad I'd ask a new question if I were you. At a guess I'd say that the output was being interpolated? I am really not sure. I'd need some data to test with.